# Perché si dice “avere la meglio”?

Tags: idioms

Qualcuno sa dire – fonti alla mano – perché si dice “avere la meglio” (per dire “riuscire superiore” etc.)? Cioè, da dove viene questa formulazione che alla lettera rasenta la scorrettezza?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In brevissimo: sembra che ci sia sempre stato.
Secondo il [dizionario Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/meglio/), è lo stesso costrutto di *la meglio gioventù*, abbreviato da *la meglio sorte*. Ci sarebbero inoltre attestazioni di *avere il meglio* in Ariosto:

> Avere la meglio (sottint. sorte o sim.), riuscire superiore, vittorioso (il contr. di avere la peggio): questa volta la m. l’hai avuta tu; non posso competere con lui, perché è più forte e avrebbe facilmente la m. su di me; anticam. si usò, con questo stesso sign., avere il m.: La battaglia durò fin alla sera, Né chi avesse anco il m. era palese (Ariosto).

In merito specificamente a *la meglio gioventù* e ad altri costrutti con *meglio*, *peggio*, *troppo* e *tanto* che sembrano o sono grammaticalmente scorretti, c'è una bella risposta di Ilaria Bonomi sul [sito della Crusca](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/avverbi-infidi/2798).

In breve, *il/la/i meglio qualcosa* con il significato di *il meglio di/fra* e *i/le migliori fra* ha diverse attestazioni scritte nel XVIII e XIX secolo e nella prima metà del XX secolo, prevalentemente per riportare un linguaggio simile al parlato. Sembra che poi, nonostante le attestazioni letterarie, non sia mai entrato a far parte del linguaggio neutro.

> Diverso il caso del tipo “la meglio gioventù” (titolo di una raccolta di poesie di Pasolini, del 1954, ripreso poi dal noto film di Marco Tullio Giordana, del 2003), in cui meglio (o peggio) in funzione di aggettivo, preceduto dall’articolo determinativo, prende il valore di superlativo relativo. Si tratta di un uso ben attestato nella storia della letteratura italiana, soprattutto dal ’700 al ’900, e ben documentato anche ai nostri giorni, come costrutto marcato e caratterizzato in senso regionale, popolare o comunque espressivo e oralizzante. Non a caso lo si trova nel genere epistolare, nella novellistica, nel discorso diretto, e nel teatro. Vediamone qualche esempio: nella “Frusta letteraria” di Giuseppe Baretti “i nostri meglio scrittori”, “voglio sapere quali paesi producono il meglio vino, e le meglio cose, e anche le peggio”; nelle Lettere del Carducci “quel pezzo è della meglio prosa che m’abbia letto”; nella novella Don Candeloro del Verga “mi rovinano la meglio scena”, nel Sor Pietro di Antonio Baldini “le meglio lettere che ho scritto le ho scritte…”; ma anche nella poesia di Montale “il meglio ramicello del tuo orto”. Un esempio particolare, proprio nella sottolineatura amaramente ironica del carattere popolare del costrutto, ne fa Pirandello, nella commedia L’innesto: “Ah, quella che è istruzione, signora mia, m'è piaciuta assai, a me, sempre! Non l'ho potuta avere io; ma le mie figliuole, per grazia di Dio, i meglio professori! Francese, inglese, la musica…”, o nella novella Donna Mimma “E che hanno da insegnare a me, che li sfascio, li sfascio tutti quanti, i meglio professori”.
>
> Il costrutto ricorre in autori soprattutto toscani, centrali e meridionali, ma non mancano esempi settentrionali come Tommaseo e De Amicis. A questi esempi registrati nel Grande Dizionario della Lingua italiana del Battaglia (GDLI), Google libri aggiunge altre attestazioni, soprattutto da testi romani e napoletani ottocenteschi, e molte da autori di narrativa contemporanea (ricerca fatta per “le meglio cose”, “le meglio donne”, “le peggio cose”).
>
> Il carattere popolare del tipo “la meglio gioventù” nell’italiano comune di oggi è indicato dai dizionari dell’uso: tra questi, il Vocabolario Treccani online precisa “vivo nell’uso popolare di tutte le regioni”, e “Anche nell’uso non strettamente popolare o regionale, quando il nome sia taciuto: questi sono i meglio che abbiamo”. I medesimi dizionari invece non marcano in alcun modo, considerandolo un uso standard, il tipo “lei è meglio di suo fratello”.
>
> Meno precise, in linea generale, sui due costrutti, la loro diffusione, il loro valore e la loro accettabilità sono le grammatiche della lingua italiana. Ne trattano in maniera più puntuale la Grammatica italiana (Italiano nella garzantina) di Luca Serianni (Serianni 1989 e 2000), sottolineando del tipo “il meglio vestito, le peggio compagnie” l’uso anche letterario, e il valore prevalentemente popolare, soprattutto ai nostri giorni; analogamente la Nuova grammatica italiana di Maurizio Dardano e Pietro Trifone (Dardano-Trifone 1997) ne rileva il valore popolare o regionale oggi, pur esistendone attestazioni letterarie. Insistono, infine, sulla popolarità e la non accettabilità del costrutto Giuseppe Patota e Valeria Della Valle nei loro manualetti normativi (Il salvalingua/Il nuovo salvalingua, Senza neanche un errore, Viva la grammatica, e altri).
>
> Concludendo, dunque, dopo questa breve documentazione della diffusione dei due costrutti in questione, del loro valore e delle indicazioni che su di essi si trovano nei principali strumenti lessicografici e grammaticali, possiamo rispondere sinteticamente così: l’uso aggettivale di meglio/peggio retto da essere, sembrare, e simili (“lei è meglio di suo fratello”), è da considerare normale e pienamente accettabile; il tipo, invece “la meglio gioventù”, largamente attestato nella storia della lingua italiana e usato da molti e grandi autori, ha carattere popolare, e come tale può, volendo, essere usato in varie occasioni, quando si voglia imprimere al discorso una particolare espressività o una punta di ironia: meglio non usarlo, invece, nella lingua neutra e non caratterizzata della comunicazione, per non correre il rischio di una stigmatizzazione anche sociale, oltre che linguistica.

Comment: Ottimo, grazie!